# Jquery Mobile app stracture

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, single-page-application

I want to build a JQM app of single page app.
I need the menu to be in a separate file and that every "page" will be also in saparate file and all the includes and the template will be in the index.html.
how can I do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JQM content visible only `data-role='page'` and you need to manage each page by `id` attribute only. And you need to manage menu, header, footer..etc for all common files to be saved in separated files, after you can load using `load()` function. Inside `$(this).trigger('create');' for applying JQM default styles and attributes. If you have any issues in this structure plz feel free to ask me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
 <head>
  <title>your app title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('pagecreate', function (event) {     
        $("[id*=header]").load('header.html', function () {
            $(this).trigger('create');
        });
    });
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="pageOne">
        <div data-role="header" id="header"></div>
        <div data-role="content">
            Page one content
        </div><!-- /content -->
    </div><!-- /page -->

    <div data-role="page" id="pageTwo">
        <div data-role="header" id="header"></div>
        <div data-role="content">
            Page two content
        </div><!-- /content -->
    </div><!-- /page -->

    <div data-role="page" id="pageThre">
        <div data-role="header" id="header"></div>
        <div data-role="content">
            Page three content
        </div><!-- /content -->
    </div><!-- /page -->
 </body>
</html>
```